# ASP is not defined at @ko.Apply(Model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I m trying to bind my model and get error
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return ASP._Page_Views_Configuration_Index_cshtml.Model().SomeProperty }"
Message: ASP is not defined

View:

```js
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")

@model Asteros.MKD.Controllers.SomeModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

@ko.Html.TextBox(model => Model.SomeProperty)


@ko.Apply(Model)
```

bundles:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

....

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js",
                "~/Scripts/perpetuum.knockout.js"
                ));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `model` instead of `Model`:

```
@ko.Html.TextBox(model => model.SomeProperty)
```